# Meaning of "Unexpected Quarters"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I am unable to find a satisfactory meaning of "**Unexpected Quarters**". According to my interpretation, it means "**unexpected ways**". But would love if someone can throw some light on this.

I searched in [this dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=unexpected%20quarter), but couldn't find the phrase.

Example Sentences :

- He received help from unexpected quarters.
- They received a large gift from an unexpected quarter.

Comment: Please show the research you have done. You should find the meaning in any good dictionary.

Comment: Searching [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quarter), the dictionary you cite, for 'quarter', one finds "**quarter** noun (PEOPLE) [C]
one or more people who provide help, information, or a particular reaction to something but who are not usually named:
_'Help came from an unexpected quarter.'_ ". I'd say the source may be more nebulous than say 'the assistant librarian', but usually involves one or more  humans (though why not a rescue dog?), and think that the PP 'from (an) unexpected quarter/s' is frozen enough that 'quarter' is perhaps better not considered count.

Comment: You should search for "unexpected" and "quarter" separately to see if any of the definitions make sense for the phrase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something coming from an **unexpected quarter** comes from an unexpected source.

For example you might need something doing which requires an unusual skill, be unable to find a suitable craftsman by searching the web or looking through the yellow pages but find, when you mention your difficulty to your neighbour in passing, that her uncle has the skill you require and is willing to do the job cheaply.

The neighbour and her uncle would be the **unexpected quarter** since you would not normally think of asking around for someone with a rare skill.

I have no proof but suspect that the term is naval in origin and refers to a 'quarter' of the compass, ie an unexpected direction. In the 18th century ship under attack from an enemy might be rescued by an ally coming from downwind, which would certainly be unexpected.

Answer (score -1):

What about just 'unexpectedness'.
See some examples from Oxford Dictionary:
The unexpectedness of this made my vision waver again as I peeked up at her.’

‘The sense of slight danger, of unexpectedness, is what they are buying into.’

‘The unexpectedness made the sting even worse of course.’